# Minimizing a function involving several modulus terms

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value, maxima-minima

$f(x)=3|x+1|+|x|+3|x-1|+2|x-3|$

**finding minimum value of this function**

One conventional way would be to make five cases regarding the various inequalities and hence simplifying to find minimum value in a graph as in 
[image]

I was trying another way

> method : Aim is to minimise each term .Since difference of x and 1 would matter thrice as much as that between x and 3 would , the value of x should be closer to 1 .

Applying this thought,x={3(1)+3(-1)+2(3)+1(0)}\9 which gives as x=2/3 . 
This way comes to be incorrect.

**I wanted to know if there were shorter solutions to this problem rather than using the graphical approach each time as when the modulus terms increase to 10 terms , it would be unreasonable to make 11 cases.**

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a convex function because a sum of convex functions is a convex function

and since the graph of $f$ is an union of segments and rays,

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$  and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$,  we obtain:

$$\min{f}=\min\{f(-1),f(0),f(1),f(3)\}=f(1)=11.$$

Comment: I don't know why this answer got down vote. Anyway it is correct and I cant imagine any other way which is shorter, faster or easier than this for this problem!

Comment: @Red shoes I think because I remember to check what happens for $x\rightarrow\infty$. I added it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We want a point where the derivative goes from negative to positive. For |x-a|, the derivative is negative if x < a and positive if x > a. If f(x) = $\sum|x-a_i|$, then the derivative at x is thus going to be (sum of all $a_i$ greater than x) minus (sum of all $a_i$ less than x). So we want a point where those are equal. That is, we want a number where as many numbers are less than it as greater than. That's called the median. Note that if you have an even number of terms, then there will be a region between the two "middle" terms where the function is constant and minimal. Also note that when calculating the median, you should take repetition into account; that is, if an absolute value term has a coefficient of n, take n copies of the associated $a_i$. For example, in this case you should take the median of -1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,3,3. And finally, note that it's a bit more complicated if some of the absolute value terms have negative coefficients.

Comment: Is there a way to prove or derive that this will always work ? Logically it seems sound.

Answer (score 0):

By triangle inequality we have for the function $$g(x) = 3|x+1|+3|x-1| = |3x+3|+|3-3x|\geq |3x+3+3-3x| =6$$
with equality exactly when $x-1$ and $x+1$ are of equal sign and this is exactly when $-1\leq x\leq 1$. But in this case we have $2|x-3| = 6-2x$. So we have

$$f(x)=g(x)+|x|+2|x-3|\geq 12-2x+|x|$$

So, if $x\geq 0$ we have $f(x) =12-x \geq 11$ and if $x\leq 0$ we have $f(x) =12-3x \geq 12$.

So $f$ achieve minimum at $x=1$ and it is $11$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  For the (convex) function $f(x) = \sum \lambda_n|x-a_n|$, ($a_n$ are distinct numbers). we always have a minimum point where derivative does not exist (it is not hard to prove this).

Hence,
 $$\min{f}=\min\{f( a_1),f(a_2),...,f(a_n)\}$$

---

I added this part to prove my claim! (Although it is somehow trivial! I am writing this exclusively for down-voter)

Proof : 
We want to show that there is a minimizer which happens to be nondifferentiable point.
we assume $\lambda_n > 0$ (actually we don't need assume this as long as we are sure minimum exist!) Let $c \in \Bbb R$ be the minimum point then it has to be critical point too which means either $f'(c) =0$ or $f'(c) = \text{does not exist}.$  In second case we are done! So assume first case has been happened. So we have $f'(c) =0$. Since $f$ is pieacewise linear, there exist a maximal interval say $[a,b]$ containing $c$ such that $f$ is constant on it. Also note $ -\infty < a< b < + \infty $ because $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = + \infty$. This shows $f(a) = f(b)= f(c)$ and so $a,b$ are minimizer too and moreover (it is easy to show that)  $a,b$ are nondifferentiable points.

**Conclusion**: In order to find a minimum point, just evaluate $f$ at Absolutvalues' roots and pick the smallest one! Then you don't need think about graphical method which may lead to $11$ cases.

Comment: You should be more precise in your wording. If you mean "If the derivative does not exist at x0, then there is a minimum point at x0", that is clearly false. If you mean "If there is a minimum point at x0, then the derivative does not exist at x0", that is also false e.g. |x-1|+|x+1| is minimal in [-1,1], but the derivative exists in (-1,1). If you  mean "There always exist an x0 such that f is minimal and f'(x0) doesn't exist", that's false if the coefficients are negative. Also, the OP clearly is aware of your method and is asking for a simpler solution, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Acccumulation  I think you should be better more precise of your understanding of things!  

I meant exactly what I said !  Minimum point is attained  where derivative does not exist ... So to find minimum point one only needs to find all nondifferentiable points  (which are finite), then compare them to find smallest one.  And Also OP wants a solution without graphing function.... I gave him the shortest possible solution which is analytic not geometric.

If you have better way, go ahead and post your own solution.

Comment: What you said was ambiguous, and all of the main interpretations are wrong. It makes no sense to say that you meant what you said, when what you said has no clear meaning. Trying to blame me for your lack of clear communication is quite immature. Mathematics is about precision, and if you want to participate in it, you need to learn how to say things clearly. More than, you need to learn how to take criticism. And  OP's main concern was having to make 11 cases, which your solution does not address. And I posted my solution more than an hour before yours.

Comment: @Acccumulation I added a proof  for you.   I admit that what I said is not clear for **you** !  I don't expect all users here understand my solution. Now I wrote a math proof for what is called ambiguous by you!   And yes "Mathematics is about precision" so please prove (at least a sketched) what you claimed in your answer as OP asked you!  rather than writing things that just come from your intuition! BTW you are not OP to insist on what I wrote is not  what OP wants.